# Transfer cell value to another cell by clicking on a button in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I want a user to be able to click on a button and have the value of one cell go into another cell.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Adapt this [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/your_first_script) to transfer value of A1 to B1:

```
function transfer() {
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    r = s.getRange("A1");
    // copyValuesToRange method will copy value in A1 to B1(range of B1 - 2,2,1,1)
    r.copyValuesToRange(s,2,2,1,1);
    r.clearContent();
}
```

Assign this script to your button.

Comment: Can I ask what the 2,2,1,1 is for?? why is it not: r.copyValuesToRange(s,"B2"); Please help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this script.
Is is possible to set the `getRange` as variable?
I have all values in column A (A1:A100)
I want to click (for example) cell A12 and the value of A12 should appear in cell L1.
If I click cell A51 it should also be copied by click into cell L1.

Comment: @user24949 This should answer your question about the 2,2,1,1 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyValuesToRange(Sheet,Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)