# How do I create a PushButton in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm new here in this site and also new in Google Apps Script.

I'm trying to find an example to create a Pushbutton inside Google sheets.

I've found [something](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/push-button) saying it is "deprecated".

What I expect to do is putting a button called "Move to Sent" that when pressed must count some lines till the line saying "END" and then move the content of those lines to another location in the same sheet.

It looks quite simple to me but I've got stuck in the very beginning.

Some help would be appreciated at least to point me in the right direction to find out.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29312/88163

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the deprecation message you found, user interfaces can be created with the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/).

But if you just want to create a button that is displayed *in your sheet*, there is an easier way.

Click *Insert → Drawing* and draw a text box. Give it a background color and a border, so that it looks something like this:

[image: A text box looking like a button]

Make sure you position the text box to the very top left corner of the drawing editor window.

When you're satisfied, click the *Save and close* button to return to your spreadsheet. The button (your drawing) is now positioned on your spreadsheet. You can click and move it anywhere you want.

Now click the button to select it, and click the little down-pointing triangle and select *Assign script*:

[image: Button positioned on spreadsheet]

In the prompt that pops up, assign a function name to your button, e.g. `clickMe`.

Next, click *Tools → Script Editor* to open the Script Editor window. Here, define your function `clickMe` (or whatever you entered in the *Assign script* popup):

```
function clickMe() {
   // Here, implement your script logic, e.g.:
   Browser.msgBox("You clicked me");
}
```

Click the *Save* button (give your script file a name when prompted) and return to your spreadsheet. Try to click the button. The first time you do so, you will be asked to give the script permission to run, and to access your spreadsheets. Having done so once, clicking the button will show a popup saying *You clicked me*.

I have created [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1snZUa-34fsLphxfhsGvqFakoRigmjrIbW3HOm8M76W8/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate, feel free to copy it. You have to be logged in order for the button to work.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another way to create a Pushbutton inside Google sheets described in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6966272).

> The apps UI only works for panels.   The best you can do is to draw a
>   button yourself and put that into your spreadsheet. Than you can add a
>   macro to it.   Go into "Insert > Drawing...", Draw a button and add it
>   to the spreadsheet. Then click it and click "assign Macro...", then
>   insert the name of the function you wish to execute there. The
>   function must be defined in a script in the spreadsheet.
>   Alternatively you can also draw the button somewhere else and insert
>   it as an image.

Comment: What I'd like to know is how this can be done using the **HTML service** mentioned [HERE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/push-button).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this answer is any different from mine?