# How to transfer a cell value to another cell by pressing a button

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to be able to click a button and the value of one cell gets transferred to another cell, and the new cell adds them up.

example:

If I put 5 in B6 then click the button, C5 should update to 5 and B6 should be cleared. If I add 5 again to B6, C5 will add 5 to its existing number adding up to 10, then B6 will be cleared.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. By the other hand, if you didn't this yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Related [How do I create a PushButton in Google Apps Script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106485/88163)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script and bind it to a button:

```
function transferCellValueOnButtonPress() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp;
    const selectedCell = ss.getCurrentCell();
    const selectedCellValue = selectedCell.getValue();

    // Target cell
    const targetCell = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("C2");

    if (!(selectedCell.isBlank() || isNaN(selectedCellValue))) {    
      // If the cell is blank or is not a number change value to 0
      if (targetCell.isBlank() || isNaN(targetCell.getValue())) {
        targetCell.setValue(0);
      }
      targetCell.setValue(targetCell.getValue() + selectedCellValue);   
    }
}
```

I have made an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10pKUQ5jTHvpuAnkTeNfSdjQnWQ-sSx6piQ1CqMgAsPU/edit?usp=sharing) which has a button that executes the script and some example values to showcase the script.

Comment: thanks a ton this helped me alot