# Google Sheets, Scroll to the bottom of each page

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have used this function to cause the page to scroll to the bottom on load. It works on the first sheet loaded but it does nothing when you change sheets. They remain at the top requiring us to scroll to the bottom.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

Could the function be linked to a button I place in the frozen header row so I can jump to the last line at any time? I dont need to select any particular row or column. Just scroll to the bottom of the page. Regardless of contents.

Comment: Welcome. It's great that you found here a script that was helpful to you but each question should include on itself all the relevant details to be responded. Please add the code here and also a brief description of your search/research efforts to adapt it your needs as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made those changes.

Comment: Checkout this [How do I create a PushButton in Google Apps Script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106485/88163)